# Shouldn't fitdist(data,'Lognormal') give the same result and plot as fitdist(log(data),'Normal') in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, histogram, curve-fitting, normal-distribution

I am trying to fit a distribution curve to the histogram of some data. (I have used some model data here instead because it is difficult to upload the actual data. I have included the complete code after my question.)

Because the histogram looks normally distributed when I plotted the x-axis in logscale, I transform the data first before fitting a normal distribution to it and I got the following results:

```
>>pdn=fitdist(log(data),'Normal')
pdn =     
  Normal distribution
       mu = -0.334458   [-0.34704, -0.321876]
    sigma =  0.351478   [0.342804, 0.360605]
```

When I plotted out the pdf with the histogram, I got this: 
[image]

The result seems reasonable to me. Then I discovered that in the Matlab `fitdist()`, it already has a 'Lognormal' option and I don't really need the transform my data first and this is what I got:

```
>>pdln = fitdist(data,'Lognormal')
pdln = 
  Lognormal distribution
       mu = -0.334458   [-0.34704, -0.321876]
    sigma =  0.351478   [0.342804, 0.360605]
```

Exactly the same mean and standard deviation as I have got before. However, when I plotted it out with the histogram, I got a different curve:
[image]

This curve fits better to the data but the positions of the mean and the mean+/-std points are not as I have expected (i.e. mean at the peak and the mean+/-std at the same levels).

Which come to my question, why would `fitdist(data,'Lognormal')` give the same result as `fitdist(log(data),'Normal')` but a different plot? I have looked through the Matlab help pages and I still could not understand why, or where are my mistakes, please help.

My aim for all this is to get some numerical parameters about the distributions of my data under different conditions and compare them to see if there is any difference. At the moment, I am not certain which way would give me reliable estimates of the means and standard deviations.

The code for the graphs is below:

```
%random data in lognormal distribution
mu=-0.335742;
sigma=0.35228;
data=lognrnd(mu,sigma,[3000 1]);

%make histogram
interval=0.1;
svalue=sort(data);
bx(1)=interval/2;
i=2;
while bx(i-1)<=max(svalue)
    bx(i)=bx(i-1)+interval;
    i=i+1;
end
by=hist(svalue,bx);

subplot(211)
h = bar(bx,by,'hist'); 
set(h,'FaceColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
set(gca,'xlim',[0.05 10]);
xticks=[0.05 0.1 0.2 0.5 1 2 5 10];
set(gca,'xscale','log','xminortick','on')   
set(gca,'xtick',xticks)
ylabel('counts')

subplot(212)
h = bar(bx,by,'hist'); 
set(h,'FaceColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
set(gca,'xlim',[0.05 10]);
xticks=[0.05 0.1 0.2 0.5 1 2 5 10];
set(gca,'xscale','log','xminortick','on')   
set(gca,'xtick',xticks)
ylabel('counts')

% fit distribution curves
pdf_x = 0:0.01:max(data);
max_by=max(by);     % for scaling the pdf to the histogram

% case 1 - PDF fitted using fitdist(log(data),'Normal')
subplot(211)
hold on
pdn = fitdist(log(data),'Normal') 
pdf_y = pdf(pdn,log(pdf_x));
h1=plot(pdf_x,pdf_y./max(pdf_y).*max_by,'-k');
range=[exp(pdn.mu-pdn.sigma) exp(pdn.mu+pdn.sigma)];
h2=plot(exp(pdn.mu),pdf(pdn,(pdn.mu))./max(pdf_y).*max_by,'sk') ;
h3=plot(range,pdf(pdn,log(range))./max(pdf_y).*max_by,'ok') ;
title('PDF fitted using fitdist(log(data),''Normal'')');
legend([h1 h2 h3],'pdf','mean','meam+/-std');

% case 2 - PDF fitted using fitdist(data,'Lognormal')
subplot(212)
hold on
pdln = fitdist(data,'Lognormal') 
pdf_y = pdf(pdln,pdf_x);
h1=plot(pdf_x,pdf_y./max(pdf_y).*max_by,'-b');
range=[exp(pdln.mu-pdln.sigma) exp(pdln.mu+pdln.sigma)];
h2=plot(exp(pdln.mu),pdf(pdln,exp(pdln.mu))./max(pdf_y).*max_by,'sb');  
h3=plot(range,pdf(pdln,range)./max(pdf_y).*max_by,'ob') ;
title('PDF fitted using fitdist(data,''Lognormal'')');
legend([h1 h2 h3],'pdf','mean','meam+/-std');
```